# MS Word: How to create numbered items/captions where the number can never be changed?

Tags: microsoft-word

If you are curious, it is for requirements management.

I know how to create a new caption, and every time I create one, it will be numbered.

The problem is that if I:

- delete one
- insert one
- move one

and then update the document, the captions get renumbered, such that #1 is always the one which appears in the document, #2 appears next & so on.

I want my captions to be given a unique number when they are created, which can never be changed.

Hmmm, I just had a thought while typing this. They don't even have to be sequential, maybe a clever use of GUID?

But, they ***do*** have to

- be collected into some sort of table of XXX, just like table of figures, etc (I know how to do this with captions which I define)
- be settable as a cross-reference, which I can click upon to jump to my caption

Can that be done?

Comment: It cannot be done simply. It is not something built into the program. Captions are numbered using SEQ fields, which must be sequential. If you substitute something else you need to keep track of the highest number. You should hire a programmer to write a program for you that uses document variable to track and insert your numbers.

Comment: I ***am*** a programmer. I am looking for a free alternative to the Doors requirements management tool, can't seem to find one & am leaning towards coding it myself.

Comment: Then use and save document variables.  This would involve creating the Caption and then running a macro that increments the variable number and replaces the SEQ field in the caption with the variable number (not a DocVariable field). This does not prevent manual changes, but will prevent any automatic changes.